# The service 'Microsoft Dynamics NAV Server [DynamicsNAV110]' (MicrosoftDynamicsNavServer$DynamicsNAV110) failed to start

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, microsoft-dynamics-nav

i am just starting with Microsoft Dynamics NAv 2018. I was never using microsoft as well as Dynamics NAV.
I am not able to install Dynamics NAV 2018 on my windows 10 Pro.
After installation I get the error message:

> The service 'Microsoft Dynamics NAV Server [DynamicsNAV110]'
>   (MicrosoftDynamicsNavServer$DynamicsNAV110) failed to start. This can
>   be caused by one of several issues. For example, the password for the
>   account that runs the service may be incorrect, or there could be a
>   conflict in port sharing for the port settings for the service, or you
>   have specified that the port for the server should be opened in the
>   Windows firewall even though the Windows firewall is not enabled on
>   the computer. For more information, see the event viewer.

I need a detailed answer with explanation, since I am beginner.

Thanks in advance and best regards!
Denis

Comment: Have you started the NAV Service?

Comment: I made sure that none of ports is used by another app. 
According installation options NT-AUTORITÄT\Netzwerkdienst is running Server service but Password field is empty since it the server is installed on my local computer?
Should I anyways type password and how to find the password???
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Which install options did you use when installing Dynamics NAV?

You have to make sure that the ports which you defined for the applications services are not used by any other program/service.
Is your service user a network user? If so, add the NT-AUTHORITY\Network Service user to your Dynamics NAV database with dbo privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Open your database in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
1) Connect your database 
2) Expand Security 
3) Expand Logins 
4) Right Click on "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" and Click on properties
5) Click on User Mapping and make sure db_owner and db_public are checked

Comment: When I click on user mapping I have 4 checboxes - (database)
1. master
2. model
3. msdb
4. tempdb

I marked all of them and on each of them I made sure that db_owner and public are checked. But anyways I cannot instal it, I always get the same error and when I try to start dynamics NAV I get the error message: the programm cannot create connection to the server.